# Saving item picked from list

Tags: c#, list, function

Main class:

```
public class Main 
{
    private string param;
    public Main(string param) { this.param = param; }

    public List<Foo> Foos
    {
        get {return GetFoos();}

        // add functionality of saving Foo (single item, not the whole list) here?
    }

    private List<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        List<Foo> x = new List<Foo>();
        return x;
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // or maybe here?
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
       var main = new Main("hi!");

       // usage 1
       main.Foos.Find(p => p.Id == 1).Save(); // method visible here

       var foo = new Main.Foo();
       // usage 2
       foo.Save(); // method not visible here
    }
}
```

Comments in the code basically say everything:
1. I want to implement the Save() method of the object Foo.
2. Method **can be** called only if the Foo object is picked up from the list (usage 1).
3. Method **can not** be called from the Foo object created alone (usage 2).
4. Method must use private value of the property **param** passed during initialization of the main class.

Comment: Well, `main.Foo.Find(p => p.Id == 1).Save()` calls the `Save` method on a `Foo` object, just like `foo.Save()` does.
If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like a `List.CurrentItem` property, or a `List.SaveCurrent` method, right? I will try to come up with a possible solution.

Comment: The `Save()` function can be defined in the `Foo` class, but it should be somehow overloaded in `Main` class. I do not want to see her if I create a new instance of this class `Foo`.

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean, but calling `main.Foo.Find(p => p.Id == 1)` will give you a `Foo` object. Would it be acceptable if only the way with `List.Find` would work the way you want it to work? Or do you want it to work for all cases of "picking an item up from the list"?

Comment: I want to use all methods to search for a specific object in the list. Once I have an object, I can call `Save ()`. Like this: `var find = main.Foos.FindLast(p => p.Id == 1); find.Save();` The reason for this is that in the `Save ()` method I want to use `param`, which is passed once during the initialization of the `Main` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface to hide the method Save.
To do this, the Save method must be implemented explicitly.
Additionally you need a link to the main object. In your subclass Foo you can access the private attribute from Main directly.

Interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    void Save();
}
```

Class:

```
public class Main
{
    private string param;
    private List<IFoo> foos = new List<IFoo>();

    public Main(string param) { this.param = param; }

    public List<IFoo> Foos
    {
        get { return this.foos; }
    }

    public void AddFoo(int pnId, string pnName)
    {
        this.foos.Add(new Foo(this) { Id = pnId, Name = pnName });
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        private Main moParent;

        public Foo() { }

        public Foo(Main poParent)
        {
            this.moParent = poParent;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //Implement interface explicitly
        void IFoo.Save()
        {
            if (this.moParent == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Parent not set");

            Console.WriteLine($"Save with Param: {this.moParent.param}, Id: {this.Id} Name: {this.Name}");
            //Save Item
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var main = new Main("hi!");

main.AddFoo(1, "Foo1");
// usage 1
main.Foos.Find(p => p.Id == 1).Save(); // method visible here

var foo = new Main.Foo();
// usage 2
//foo.Save(); // Save is not visible here
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks!